# How to train a convolution neural network with my own dataset for image clasification and save it as .pb.Everything in tensorflow and python

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to learn how to train a convolution neural network in tensorflow.May you write a link with some code.For example a github project.After I train the convolution neural network with my own dataset ,how to save it as .pb or .pbtxt.May you discribe the procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure if you want code you can understand or just a model. If you want just the model check out this [retraining code of tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/examples/image_retraining). For full understanding, this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/pouryaayria/convolutional-neural-networks-tutorial-tensorflow) might be useful. The pb file you're referring to is also called a saved model, see this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#simple_save).